# Jekyll posts format displaying properly locally, yet not on internet

Tags: jekyll

When I run my site locally, it looks like this: [image]

**However**, when actually looking at it on the internet, it does not apply the CSS it seems to me: [image]

Does anyone have advice for why it may be doing that?

**UPDATE**

I think I see where it is going wrong, though I do not know why.
In the head.html file, I have the line 
 `link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ site.baseurl }}public/css/poole.css"`

On the local Jekyll server running on my ubuntu instance, when viewing the page source, the above line from the head.html gets translated to:
`<link rel="stylesheet" href="/public/css/poole.css">`

Whereas when I look up the site online, the same string gets translated to:
`<link rel="stylesheet" href="public/css/poole.css">`

The lack of slash causes the link to search in the current path instead of the root path. I am trying to figure out why the slash is not included when ran on the internet.

Comment: I have jekyll serving it to me locally on my ubuntu machine, and then it is deployed to github pages

Comment: I have been migrating my content to the hyde theme

Comment: Note that the homepage works correctly. It looks like you're using relative instead of absolute links for the CSS, so any page other than the homepage 404s on the stylesheets.

Comment: That makes sense, I think that could be the case. I will look more into that! Thanks

Comment: Looking at https://github.com/ashears/ashears.github.io/blob/master/_includes/head.html#L18 it seems `{{ site.baseurl }}` is coming up empty, but I don't know enough about Jekyll to tell you why.

Answer (score 0):

1. In **_config.yml** change `baseurl: /` to  `baseurl: ''`
2. call your assets with `{{ site.baseurl }}/path/to/file`

In your code it's :

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ site.baseurl }}public/css/poole.css">`

or in [jekyll minima](https://github.com/jekyll/minima/blob/master/_includes/head.html) :

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ "/assets/main.css" | relative_url }}">`

Comment: so since the baseurl is just an empty string, I'm guessing that "/path/to/file" needs to be the entire pathname, i.e. ashears@github.io/<file> . Wouldn't this make it so that it would not work when ran locally on my development machine which runs at localhost:4000 ?

Comment: For some reason, the link in that format yields the following string in the page source:

Locally: <link rel="stylesheet" href="/public/css/poole.css">
Internet:  <link rel="stylesheet" href="public/css/poole.css">

The slash is not showing in the html code when the site is on the internet but it does when it is local

Answer (score 0):

**Update:**

The solution below seems to be working as expected. The OP has made the changes and is using relative links which are working as expected.

[image]

[image]

You can simply use relative paths. There's no need for the entire URL. It will also load faster.

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="/public/css/poole.css">`

If you still need to load the assets from the **internet** for any reason, then I suggest you use the `site.url` variable from your `_config.yml` file.

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ site.url }}public/css/poole.css">`

Jekyll handles this automatically, meaning that if you're running the site locally, it will replace it with your localhost URL and vice versa when on the remote.

Comment: This is a really bad advice. One must use `site.baseurl` to ensure assets reachability in any case. For example, this will fail if code is hosted on a project repository.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback but can you please direct the OP and me to some docs verifying your comment? Base URL is not a default variable in Jekyll whilst URL is.

Comment: You can fork **git@github.com:ashears/ashears.github.io.git** an see by yourself that, as it's forked as a project repository (available at https://keithmifsud.github.io/ashears.github.io/), and that your advise is wrong.
`<link rel="stylesheet" href="/public/css/poole.css">` will be 404, as well as `<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ site.url }}public/css/poole.css">`.
I'm answering questions like "where are my jekyll assets ?" since some years now, an believe me I know what I'm talking about.

Comment: @DavidJacquel This is not a project page and if it was the URL will not be  `keithmifsud.github.io/ashears.github.io` but `USERNAME.github.io/REPO_NAME` and in that case, the project side of it may have it's own `baseurl`. This one does not and will not need it. It is simply an empty property in the Ops `_config.yml` file.